# how to do gradle dependency project to each other

Tags: gradle, build, dependencies

Good day,

Previously I was using eclipse IDE to do the project dependency. So my project A can import class from project B, and also project B can import project A.

Now I am changing to `gradle`.  The following is my gradle code:

```
project('host-A') {

  dependencies {
    compile project(':host-B')
  }
  host.ext.A = project
}
```

With this, my project A able to import class from project B.

However, I wish to make the project B able to import class from project A as well, but I am hitting error if I code the `gradle` as follow:

```
project('host-B') {

  dependencies {

   compile project(':host-A')

  }
  host.ext.B = project
}
```

I believe there should be a way to do this. May I know what is my mistake? I am new to `gradle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe there should be a way to do this.

There is none. Cyclic dependencies only work in Gradle if the configuration itself is cyclic free, for example: Project `A` has a `compile` dependency to `B` and `B` has a `testCompile` dependency to `A`. Both depending on each other for `compile` won't work.

Maybe you can rework your project setup? It is quite common to extract base functionality into separate projects, say project `C`. This way both `A` and `B` could depend on `C` without depending on each other.